# Inserting formulas w/ FOR NEXT Loop

Tags: excel, vba

Couldn't find a thread that would answer my question, os here I am.  Please provide a link if there is one that I have not found.

Using Excel 2010
The comments should be sufficient to show what I'm trying to do.
I'm getting the Application-defined or Object-defined error (Runtime error 1004)  I just can figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.  Side note: I can get the loop to work when a formula like =if(A1=B1,"",3)  If actually places the formula in the cell and show 3 in each cell when the condition is met.  it just adding the Column,Row, I've tried & Range($, C) &, all sorts of combinations so, show me how much of a boob I am and help me with the SIMPLE fix that eludes me.

Thanks in advance.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim R, C As Integer
Dim Frmla1, Frmla2, Frmla3 As String
R = 4                               'Initial Row #
C = 2                               'Initial Column #
Frmla1 = "=IF('Log Sheet'!"         '1st half of the formula
Frmla2 = "="""","""",'Log Sheet'!"  '2nd half of the formula
Frmla3 = ")"                        'Closing Parenthesis

' The Cells should have incremental Column,Row Identifiers.
' The following is what I want in each cell.
' The problem is trying to get the B4 and B5 into the formula.
' Formula "=IF('Log Sheet'!B4="","",'Log Sheet'!B4)
' Formula "=IF('Log Sheet'!B5="","",'Log Sheet'!B5)

        For R = 4 To 301
            ActiveSheet.Cells(R, C).Value = Frmla1 & R & C & Frmla2 & R & C & Frmla3

            R = R + 2
        Next R
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using the **R** and **C** to reference a [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) that you can return a [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) from.

```
    For R = 4 To 301 Step 2
        ActiveSheet.Cells(R, C).Formula = _
          Frmla1 & Cells(R, C).Address(0, 0) & Frmla2 & Cells(R, C).Address(0, 0) & Frmla3
    Next R
```

I've also removed your `R = R + 2` and changed the **Step** of the For ... Next to increment by 2. You shouldn't self-increment a For ... Next inside the loop.

I changed the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) assignment to [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx). While your method often works, it wasn't correct and if the cells were formatted as Text, the formulas would come into the cells as text-that-looks=like-a-formula.

Your variable declarations should be more like the following.

```
Dim R As Long, C As Long
Dim Frmla1 As String, Frmla2 As String, Frmla3 As String
```

Each declaration should carry a variable type. Without it, they are declared as object/variant types,

Comment: After rereading the comments in your code I am not sure what the `R = R + 2` is supposed to do. Perhaps the `Step 2` is not the correct syntax.